# How to use GetStringAsync in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, http

I don't really know what I'm going. Trying to gather small pieces of code from the web

I ended up with this:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Module Module1


    Sub Main()
        LoadData()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub LoadData()
        Dim client As New Net.Http.HttpClient()
        Dim url = "my url which return json"
        Dim uri As New Uri(url)
        Dim json As String = Await client.GetStringAsync(uri)
        Dim j = JObject.Parse(json)("TIME SERIES INTRADAY")
        Dim openPrice = j("1. open").Value(Of Double)

        Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(openPrice)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
End Module
```

There is no issue when I build but when I run, I get this erroer message when I step on row

```
Dim json As String = Await client.GetStringAsync(uri)
```

error code:

```
The program '[4032] AVT.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Do you know why this line is returning this error?
Framework 4.5

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do top-level `Await` in a console program.  You can still make it work (preserving the `Async` on `LoadData`) with the following changes:

1. Change the signature of `LoadData` to `Private Async Function LoadData() As Task`
2. Change the call in `Main` to `LoadData.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

This will block in `Main` which is fine because there is no message loop to support a non-blocking wait.  This is only appropriate in a console program, if you were doing this in any other setting your original implementation would have been correct (except that you should always use `Async Function ... As Task` in preference to `Async Sub` in any context aside from event handlers).

Comment: Thank you Craig,
I applied you piece of code but It results in:
System.NullReferenceException

I might consider to avoid this Task/async method that I'm not familiar with but the GetString is only available with the Async mode for what I see

Comment: Async main method is supported

Comment: @Magnus It didn't seem to be in VS 2017 in .NET Framework through I think 4.7.  I had to do the material I included above.

Comment: @vib If you're getting a nullref exception, then I would recommend debugging to see where it arises.  You can step into async code without issues.  I suspect you might have an issue with this: `j("1. open").Value(Of Double)`; I could imagine `j("1. open")` returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this even in a console application. 
I suggest you to use an `ApplicationContext` in order to keep all alive. 
Doing as you shows, so, calling your `LoadData()`
your `Main` Sub going tasks are:

1. Enter
   *(and immediately after)*
2. Exit

. 
Take a look on code below to figure out the mechanism that you need to do what you want to do.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

    Module Module1

        Public Class MyApplicationContext
            Inherits ApplicationContext

            Private Async Sub LoadData()
                Dim client As New Net.Http.HttpClient()
                Dim url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324373/how-to-use-getstringasync-in-vb-net"
                Dim uri As New Uri(url)
                Dim json As String = Await client.GetStringAsync(uri)
                Console.WriteLine(json)
                Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json)

                'Dim j = JObject.Parse(json)("TIME SERIES INTRADAY")
                'Dim openPrice = j("1. open").Value(Of Double)
                'Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(openPrice)
                Console.ReadLine() 'Here is stopped/waiting for user

                'Here your application can be stopped after her work
                'Application.Exit()
            End Sub

            Public Sub New()
                MyBase.New()
                AddHandler Application.ApplicationExit, AddressOf OnApplicationExit
                LoadData()
            End Sub

            Private Sub OnApplicationExit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
                Try
                    ' delete your data here
                Catch
                End Try
            End Sub

        End Class

        Public Sub Main()
            Dim context As MyApplicationContext = New MyApplicationContext()
            Application.Run(context)
        End Sub


    End Module
```